# connect ETIMEDOUT when tryin to connect to AWS PostgresSQL DB

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-rds-data-service

I am getting an error when I try to connect to my DB and I have no clue how to fix this. I am using the VSCode extension by Chris Kolkman. After I enter information about my DB to establish a connection, I get stuck at this step:

`[Optional] The database to connect to. Leave empty to enumerate databases on the server (Press 'Enter' to confirm or 'Escape' to cancel)`

There are no databases listed and after sitting here for a little bit I get the error. I have no clue how to fix this and would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

I also want to note that I installed PostgresSQL using homebrew instead of an installer like I see a lot of people do, but I don't think that should have much of an impact.

Comment: You used homebrew on AWS?

Comment: @jjanes no I used homebrew to install psql

Answer (score 1):

You can be seeing an issue when using the VSCode PostgreSQL extension to connect to your PostgreSQL database for a number of reasons. Use the `brew services list` command to check that your PostgreSQL server is up and running; if it isn't, start it with `brew services start postgresql` to fix the issue. Check your connection information—including the hostname, port, username, and password—a second time to be sure it is accurate. Make sure the connection is not being blocked by your network setup or firewall settings. Try pressing Enter during connection setup without entering any data in the "*Database*" form if you still aren't able to list databases. By connecting to the PostgreSQL server in this manner, you can manually specify the database name in your SQL queries and connect to the server without identifying a specific database. It's also crucial to evaluate the configuration options for your VSCode PostgreSQL extension and maintain it updated. The documentation for the extension can provide particular troubleshooting instructions, and checking logs for error messages can provide insightful information. If the problem doesn't go away, think about asking for help in the VSCode community or on the extension's GitHub source for more specialised support.